# What is the word for when something is currently unavailable?

Tags: latin, greek

I think it starts with L (also maybe latin origin)
For example I'm waiting to get a package but I'm not even sure package has been even sent. *So package is in L...* (maybe not best example, I'm not even sure true meaning of word)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the word ***limbo***.  The Oxford Living Dictionaries defines it as:

> ***[limbo](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/limbo)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> *[mass noun]*
>
> 1. (in some Christian beliefs) the supposed abode of the souls of unbaptized infants, and of the just who died before Christ's coming.
> 2. An uncertain period of awaiting a decision or resolution; an intermediate state or condition.
>
>    *‘the legal battle could leave the club in limbo until next year’*
>
>    2.1 A state of neglect or oblivion.
>
>    *‘these prisoners are in limbo: no one is responsible for their welfare’*

In your example, it would be:

> *So, the package is in **limbo**.*

Also, Oxford notes that it is from the latin:

> **Origin**
> Late Middle English: from the medieval Latin phrase in limbo, from limbus ‘hem, border, limbo’.

The Online Etymology Dictionary goes into [a little more detail](https://www.etymonline.com/word/limbo#etymonline_v_9526), if you're interested.

Here are a few examples from recent news headlines:

[Florence's Slow-Motion Havoc Leaves Thousands of Evacuees in Limbo](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/09/26/us/flooding-carolinas-florence-evacuees.html)
[Dozens of distressed migrants in limbo after Panama withdraws rescue ship's registration at sea](https://abcnews.go.com/International/dozens-migrants-limbo-panama-withdraws-rescue-ships-registration/story?id=58042232)
[New York Philharmonic Musicians In Limbo After Investigation](https://www.npr.org/2018/09/17/648742433/new-york-philharmonic-musicians-in-limbo-after-investigation)